# Sleep modes on Raspberry Pi Pico / RP2040

Tags: microcontroller, rp2040, raspberry-pi-pico

I am developing a circuit with Raspberry Pi Pico. To power the system from battery, I need to put the Raspberry Pi Pico / RP2040 into sleep mode in order to increase energy efficiency. For this purpose, I used the hello_sleep and hello_dormant examples from the Raspberry Pi Pico examples as a base, added functionality to save and restore clock registers, but encountered two problems:

1. Whenever I put the MCU into sleep mode, there will be no more output from printf visible on the serial monitor. Output to SSD1306 works as expected.
2. After a couple of sleep phases, the MCU seems to freeze.

Did anyone else encounter similar problems and could come up with a solution?
Is there any working example for putting the Raspberry Pi Pico or other RP2040-based boards into sleep mode?

All hints are highly appreciated.

Comment: if you put the device to sleep then uart output is expected to stop.  It would not be in a low power sleep mode if it was still sending out data on the uart.   The display is expected to keep the last thing written to it, but if there is activity to the display then you are not in a sleep mode.

Comment: you need to provide a minimal complete example.

Comment: I do not expect that the UART works during deep sleep, but after deep sleep. I have an example which is not minimal, but easy to understand. 
In the repository https://github.com/ms1963/SleepyPico it is the file SleepyPico.cpp that shows an example. Look at the while loop at the end of main() as well as the functions before_sleep(), start_sleep(), and after_sleep().